# Java newInstance call for JavaHelp crashing with createUI error on second and subsequent calls

Tags: java, classloader, javahelp

In my app I am dynamically loading the jhall file for JavaHelp, so my code uses reflection.  The weird thing is that it works fine for the first call, and my JavaHelp screens show up fine, with all the navigation.  If I close my JavaHelp screen, and open it again, I get the message:

> UIDefaults.getUI() failed: createUI() failed for javax.help.JHelpContentViewer[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=] java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   java.lang.Error

This happens on all JavaHelp requests except the first.  However, no exception is caught, and I tried catching the createUI error, and that didn't catch anything either (apparently that's not surprising).  It may be a class loader problem - I'm a bit shaky on class loaders - but no exceptions are caught...  I really need some help in trouble-shooting this bug.  TIA

FWIW, (most of) the code is as follows - jHelpClass and helpSetClass are declared elsewhere...

```
jHelpClass = null;
helpSetClass = null;
URLClassLoader cl = null;

File jFile = new File(jhallJarFile);
if (!(jFile.exists())) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"JavaHelp jar file shown in properties does not exist");
    return;
}
try {
    URI uri = jFile.toURI();
    URL url = uri.toURL();
    URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

    // Create a new class loader with the directory
    cl = new URLClassLoader(urls, this.getClass().getClassLoader());

    jHelpClass = cl.loadClass("javax.help.JHelp");

    // Find the HelpSet file and create the HelpSet object
    helpSetClass = cl.loadClass("javax.help.HelpSet");
} catch (MalformedURLException e2) {
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e2) {
} catch (NoClassDefFoundError e2) {
}

if (jHelpClass == null || helpSetClass == null) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
            "JHelp class or HelpSet class not found in jar file");
    return;
}

// HelpSet hs = null;

URL url = null;
//Object hv = null;
JComponent hv = null;
try {
    url = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResource("helpSet.hs");
    if (url == null) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "HelpSet not found");
        return;
    }


    Constructor conhs = helpSetClass.getConstructor(
            ClassLoader.class, URL.class);
    //Object hs = conhs.newInstance(null, url);
    Object hs = conhs.newInstance(cl, url);
    Constructor conjh = jHelpClass.getConstructor(helpSetClass);
    hv = (JComponent) conjh.newInstance(hs);

} catch (Exception e2) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
            "HelpSet could not be processed: " + e2);
    return;
}           

// Create a new frame.
final JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
frame2.setTitle("Help DrawFBP");
frame2.setIconImage(favicon.getImage());
//frame2.setRequestFocusEnabled(true);
frame2.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
            //frame2.setVisible(false);
            frame2.dispose();
        }
    }
});
// Set its size.
frame2.setPreferredSize(frame.getPreferredSize());
// Add the created helpViewer to it.
frame2.getContentPane().add(hv);code
// Set a default close operation.
frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
// Make the frame visible.
frame2.setVisible(true);
frame2.pack();
return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I can fix this problem by hanging onto the variable called "hv" (the JHelp instance), and not recalculating it each time - apparently all that reloading somehow damaged the classes in storage...?  Don't know if this makes sense, but it my app is currently working.  I would be interested in knowing more about what actually caused this, and if there are techniques to troubleshoot it in the future, but clearly a solution is no longer urgent!  Thanks to anyone who spent time on this.